# Powershell Try&Catch Run multiple commands inside try

Tags: powershell, try-catch, powershell-2.0

Hi I am trying to figure out how to do this or another way of doing it

```
try {
Get-ADComputer -Identity namedoesnotexist
(Get-ChildItem).FullName
}
catch {$_ | Out-File log.log}
```

When running this code I am using a name that does not exist so I get an error and catch will write this to my logfile (just an example)
What I want to accomplish is that the error is catched but the try statement continues to run my Get-Childitem command and tries that too.
Any other simple way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put just one line in the try..catch will give you that effect

```
try 
{
  Get-ADComputer -Identity namedoesnotexist
}
catch 
{
  $_ | Out-File log.log
}
(Get-ChildItem).FullName
```

But maybe [trap](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847742.aspx) is what you are looking for

```
trap
{
  $_ | Out-File log.log
  continue # remove this if you still want to see each error
}
Get-ADComputer -Identity namedoesnotexist
(Get-ChildItem).FullName
```

Comment: use the `-Append` switch for `Out-File` so you don't overwrite the log file on each error.